# Special Characters getting morphed to their XML number reference Java, tomcat9

Tags: java, tomcat9

I recently updated one of my apps from Tomcat6 to Tomcat9 and Java8 to OpenJDK 11, Linux and I was seeing a problem with my forms when I submit special characters such as Japanese/Chinese characters.

It doesn't look like the issue is coming from code since I tried running the app in my old Tomcat6/Java8 box and the special characters are not being converted. It might be some server configuration but I'm not really sure where to look.

I input "法敲中" and it gets converted into &# 27861; &# 25970; &# 20013; once I submit my forms

Comment: In my browser, input and result do look the same …

Comment: are you getting any exception? In question  both string look same 法敲中

Comment: Just edited. XML number reference is getting converted here

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be normal behavior. The numbers you see are XML encoding that is equivalent to "\u6cd5\u6572\u4e2d" - unicode codes for the symbols "法敲中" XML parser wants to ensure that the xml String could be passed with simple English encoding (ISO8859-1) and those symbols could not be passed in that encoding. So it converts it to unicode equivalents so later it could still "understand" and decode non-standard symbols even though ISO8859-1 charset doesn't support them. This is a precaution since if you work with UTF-8 it would pass just fine. Anyway I used a tool to test it that I find very useful. It converts any String into Unicode characters and back. Here is what I did:

```
System.out.println(StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence("法敲中"));
```

And the result came as `\u6cd5\u6572\u4e2d`. If you wish to use this tool, it is part of the MgntUtils open source library (written by me). Here are the links to [Maven Artifacts](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils), [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) (including sources and javadoc) and [javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/). Also you can read about the library [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really want to do encoding for each of my input fields yet. As I was investigating what I had so far was that I saw in my response headers that I have the `Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1` I'm guessing the charset of ISO-8859-1 is what's causing them to get converted? I still have no idea where I can modify this though.

Comment: Yes you are correct, charset of ISO-8859-1 is what's causing them to get converted.